# How can I avoid to make waste column in Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables `User` and `Message` like below:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public partial class Message
{
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    public int SenderID { get; set; }
    public int ReceiverID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyToMessaageID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public virtual User SenderUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ReceiverUser { get; set; }

}
```

And in domain layer class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //Configure domain classes using modelBuilder here
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasOptional(c => c.Messages)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReplyToMessaageID);
       modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                 .HasRequired(c => c.SenderUser)
                 .WithMany(c => c.Messages)
                 .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderID)
                 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                 .HasRequired(c => c.ReceiverUser)
                 .WithMany(c => c.Messages)
                 .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReceiverID)
                 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Everything is fine but as can be seen in the final result, `Message` table has a waste column with name `User_UserID`.

[image]

How can I avoid creating it?

Comment: What is the purpose of `public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }` in `User`? Is that supposed to be the user's sent messages or received messages?  Because that is what is adding the field.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks sir. By removing that the waste column `User_UserID` has been deleted. 
But how could i access to `Message` from `User` in query by deleting `public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }` ??

Comment: Again, is that supposed to be the user's sent messages or received messages?

Comment: As Paul implies, you need 2 collections: SentMessages and ReceivedMessages on your User class. Then indicate each in the fluent code.

Comment: @PaulAbbott tnx so much +1

Comment: @SteveGreene tnx sir. i do it.